# Refreshing access tokens every one hour OAuth Android

Tags: android, oauth, access-token

Iam have implemented OAuth in my Android app. When I sign in I get an Access token with a refresh token and expiry time. The Access token Expires in 1 hour. I know how to request for a fresh access token from a refresh token but I am not sure of how to do it when it reaches the expiry time.

Here is my code:-

```
mMap = helper.getUserDetails();

                    mAccessToken =  mMap.get("accesstoken");
                    mRefreshToken = mMap.get("refresh_token");
                    mExpiresIn = mMap.get("expires_in");
                    mExpiresOn = mMap.get("expires_on");
                    mIdToken = mMap.get("id_token");
                    mScope = mMap.get("scope");
                    mTokenType = mMap.get("token_type");
                    userName = mMap.get("username");
                    firstName = mMap.get("name");





private class RefreshTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /**
             * Check if access token is expired
             * Request new  access token  by passing refresh token 
             */
            String mUrl = Constants.LOGIN_URL + Constants.TENANT +"/oauth2/token";

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(mUrl);
            int expiryHour = (Integer.parseInt(mExpiresIn)/60)/60;



            try 
            {
                List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", Constants.CLIENT_ID));

                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("refresh_token", mRefreshToken));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse refreshResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity refreshEntity = refreshResponse.getEntity();
                result = EntityUtils.toString(refreshEntity);

                //Deserialize the data into JSON
                JSONObject refreshStatusObject = new JSONObject(result);
                //Pull values out of the JSON
                mAccessToken = refreshStatusObject.getString("access_token");
                Log.i(TAG, "Access Token: " + mAccessToken);
                mExpiresIn = refreshStatusObject.getString("expires_in");
                mRefreshToken = refreshStatusObject.getString("refresh_token");
                mPortalId = refreshStatusObject.getString("portal_id");

                int firstIndex = mAccessToken.indexOf(".");
                int secondIndex = mAccessToken.indexOf(".", firstIndex+2);
                String claims = mAccessToken.substring(firstIndex + 1, secondIndex);
                //Decode base64 URL ended claims
                byte[] data = Base64.decode(claims, Base64.URL_SAFE);

                String text = new String(data, "ASCII");
                //Display claims on screen

                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(text);
                //Get and display the logged in user name
                userName = jObject.getString("unique_name");
                firstName = jObject.getString("given_name");

                helper.createLoginSession(mAccessToken, mExpiresIn, mExpiresOn, mIdToken, mRefreshToken, mResource, mScope, mTokenType, userName, firstName);
            } 
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, SUpdate.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an Android [Authenticator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Authenticator.html) for this. Then you will use the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to ask for the token. Your custom authenticator will then get called. In that authenticator you will need to check to see if the current access token you have is expired. If it is, make a call with the refresh token and get a new one, update the auth token in the account manager and then return it to the caller.

Therefore your app doesn't need to know the details of how and when to update the token, it simply knows "I need a token, let me get one from the AccountManager" and then the account manager and authenticator take over and do the rest for you.

Here's [a good tutorial on building your own Authenticator](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/).